# Running awk through a redirection

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following `bash` code that calls `awk` through a redirection.

`lnum` is a comma separated sequence of numbers which are used to
colour the strings being passed as input.  The input strings are supposed to be printed on separate lines.

```
firefly () {
 sgr="$( tput sgr0 )"
 blu="$( tput bold; tput setaf 39 )"

 lseq="1,2"

 awk -v frg="$blu" -v rst="$sgr" -v lnum="$lseq"  \
  'BEGIN { split(lnum, laggr, ",") }
   {
    found = 0
    for (item in laggr) {
       if (laggr[item] == NR) { found = 1 ; break }
     }

    if (found) { fm="%s%s%s\n" ; printf(fm, frg, $0, rst) }
    else { fm = "%s\n" ; printf(fm, $0) }
  }' <<< "$@"

 }
```

I am running this using

```
firefly "First Line" "Second Line" "Third Line"
```

But am getting the three strings printed on the same line rather than en separate lines.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What's the output and what your desired output?

Comment: Replace `<<< "$@"` with `< <(printf '%s\n' "$@")`

Comment: `<<<"$@"` doesn't make sense. `"$@"` is an array. If you try to serialize an array into a string, bash falls back to doing the same thing as `"$*"`, separating each element with the first character from `$IFS`.

Comment: (you can't write an array into a string directly without creating ambiguity because an array is a _list_ of strings; there's no character that could be used to separate list elements that wouldn't also be valid _inside_ one of those elements; the one character that isn't valid in a C string is the NUL byte, but because it's not valid in a string that bash can store in memory, bash can't have a parameter expansion generate it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding M.NejatAydin's suggestion and some tweaks to OP's current `awk` code:

```
awk -v frg="$blu" -v rst="$sgr" -v lnum="$lseq" '
BEGIN { n=split(lnum,a,",")
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)                                # loop through array and ...
            laggr[a[i]]                                   # assign values as indices in new array
        fm1="%s%s%s\n"                                    # define formats once per program invocation ...
        fm2="%s\n"                                        # instead of once for each line of input
      }
      { if (NR in laggr) printf(fm1, frg, $0, rst)        # if NR is an index in the array
        else             printf(fm2, $0)
      }
' < <(printf "%s\n" "$@")                                 # M.NejatAydin's suggestion
```

**NOTE:** the rest of OP's current code remains as is

A bit less typing using a ternary operator (aka [conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html)) and the knowledge that a format of `%0.s` effectively ignores the associated arg:

```
awk -v frg="$blu" -v rst="$sgr" -v lnum="$lseq" '
BEGIN { n=split(lnum,a,",")
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            laggr[a[i]]
        fm1="%s%s%s\n"
        fm2="%0.s%s%0.s\n"             # ignore 1st and 3rd args to printf
      }
      { printf ((NR in laggr) ? fm1 : fm2), frg, $0, rst }
' < <(printf "%s\n" "$@")
```

Reduce to one format variable and use the ternary to determine the 1st arg to `printf`:

```
awk -v frg="$blu" -v rst="$sgr" -v lnum="$lseq" '
BEGIN { n=split(lnum,a,",")
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            laggr[a[i]]
        fm="%s%s%s\n"
      }
      { printf fm, ((NR in laggr) ? frg : rst), $0, rst }
' < <(printf "%s\n" "$@")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
firefly () {
    local lseq="$1"
    local color="$2"
    local style="$3"
    shift 3

    awk -v lnum="$lseq"  -v cl="$color" -v st="$style" '
        function colorit(str, c){return "\033["colors[c]"m"str"\033[0m"}
        function styleit(str, s){return "\033["styles[s]"m"str"\033[0m"}
        BEGIN { 
            colors["red"] = 31; colors["blue"] = 36; colors["yellow"] = 33
            styles["normal"] = 2; styles["bold"] = 1; styles["italic"] = 3;
            styles["underscore"] = 4;
            split(lnum, tmp, ","); for(i in tmp) laggr[tmp[i]]
        }
        NR in laggr { print styleit(colorit($0, cl),st); next }
    1' < <(printf '%s\n' "$@")
 }
```

[image]